# How to attach onchange event to CheckBoxList? Missing InputAttributes?

Tags: asp.net, checkboxlist

Setting onchange event for CheckBoxList using the following code doesn't work.

```
chkListUserGroup.Attributes.Add("onchange", "document.forms[0].isRecordModified.value='true';");
```

How to set onchange event for CheckBoxList?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What does the rendered HTML look like?

Comment: Yeap, as long as you give it out, we cannot find accurate answer.

Comment: onchange event is attached to label element not to input label itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use onclick event,

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            CheckBoxList1.Items.Add("A");
            CheckBoxList1.Items.Add("B");
            CheckBoxList1.Items.Add("C");
            CheckBoxList1.Items.Add("D");

            foreach (ListItem item in CheckBoxList1.Items)
            {
                item.Attributes.Add("onclick", "document.forms[0].isRecordModified.value=document.activeElement.checked");    
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is the only way I have managed to catch the event for check box lists

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to handle the events of click in Check box list in vb.net

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not IsPostBack Then
            Dim li As ListItem
            For Each li In CheckboxList1.Items
                li.Attributes.Add("onclick", "alert('hello')")
            Next
        End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Well actually it should be working. Because I write something in my code and it worked. It seems you need to check your javascript code by simply changing it with alert('hello');

```
 foreach (ListItem item in CheckBoxList1.Items)
 {
    item.Attributes.Add("onchange", "alert('hello')");
 }
```

This is my simple code and it is working.

Comment: @Aaron: I just deleted my answer, as you are absolutely right. Didn't know that the onchange event would automatically propagate to child elements.

Comment: How to set it for an item in CheckBoxList. onchange event is attached to label element not to input label itself.

Comment: The same issue, it affects label not input element.
this is how it's rendered ...


<SPAN onchange="document.forms[0].isRecordModified.value='true';"><INPUT id=chkListUserGroup_2 tabIndex=6 onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'chkListUserGroup$2\',\'\')', 0)" type=checkbox name=chkListUserGroup$2><LABEL for=chkListUserGroup_2>ACCOUNTS USER GROUP</LABEL></SPAN>